# jQuery: select default value and trigger change for multiple Selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, triggers

I am new to jQuery and found a couple of different approaches for this online but nothing worked for me so I hope someone can help me.

I have a **number of Selects**. Each of them has **one option with a class** `"defaultSel"` to indicate that this should be selected as the default when a certain event is triggered.

My approach was the following which does change the Selects value but I can't get it to actually trigger the change (neither adding `.change()` nor `.trigger('change')` worked for me here). 
Also, if there is a way to avoid `.each` here at all please let me know as well.

**My jQuery:**

```
$(this).closest('div').nextAll('div.hiddenDiv').show().find('.defaultSel').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('selected', true).change();
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help, 
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `option` is the thing with the defaultSel class then this should work:

```
$(this).closest('div').nextAll('div.hiddenDiv').show().find('select:has(option.defaultSel)').each(function(){
    $(this).find('option.defaultSel').prop('selected', true).end().change();
});
```

Just changing two things here:

```
find('select:has(option.defaultSel)')
```

will get the `select` set you're actually wanting, and

```
$(this).find('option.defaultSel').prop('selected', true).end().change();
```

`this` here is the `select` so you need to find the default option, then `end()` will return you to the `select` and you can trigger `change()` on it.

Comment: Yes, the option has the class. Thanks a lot for this - it works fantastic ! - And the explanations are really helpful too. Will accept as soon as I can. :)